# java.sql.BatchUpdateException: transaction too large, len:300200

Tags: mysql, apache-spark, jdbc, tidb

got this error when writing into tidb use jdbc drive in spark2.2:

```
java.sql.BatchUpdateException: transaction too large, len:300200
```

got the error under condition:
   `select whole table`

not getting error under condition :
 `select with limit 10000000;`

haven't got any clue

Comment: I dig a little bit and it seems only set / update should trigger that error message. It confused me that select query will go through update code path. Would you please paste the full exception stack and explain a little bit what you were doing when error happened?

Answer (score 1):

Copy from [TiDB document](https://github.com/pingcap/docs/blob/master/FAQ.md#the-error-message-transaction-too-large-is-displayed)

> The error message transaction too large is displayed.
>
> As distributed transactions need to conduct two-phase commit and the
>   bottom layer performs Raft replication, if a transaction is very
>   large, the commit process would be quite slow and the following Raft
>   replication flow is thus struck. To avoid this problem, we limit the
>   transaction size:
>
> Each Key-Value entry is no more than 6MB The total number of Key-Value
>   entry is no more than 300,000 rows The total size of Key-Value entry
>   is no more than 100MB There are similar limits on Google Cloud
>   Spanner.
>
> Solution:
>
> When you import data, insert in batches and it'd be better keep the
>   number of one batch within 10,000 rows.
>
> As for insert and select, you can open the hidden parameter set
>   @@session.tidb_batch_insert=1;, and insert will execute large
>   transactions in batches. In this way, you can avoid the timeout caused
>   by large transactions, but this may lead to the loss of atomicity. An
>   error in the process of execution leads to partly inserted
>   transaction. Therefore, use this parameter only when necessary, and
>   use it in session to avoid affecting other statements. When the
>   transaction is finished, use set @@session.tidb_batch_insert=0 to
>   close it.
>
> As for delete and update, you can use limit plus circulation to
>   operate.